# Regular expression to match every occurrence outside brackets?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
FROM {oj table1 left outer join table2 on table1.field1 = table2.field1}, table1, table3
```

How can I match the `table1` outside the braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want `table1` outside the brackets.

```
/table1(?=,)/
```

or

```
/table1[^\}]+/
```

Comment: Neither of these worked.  The first one returned nothing, and the 2nd returned 1 item, within the braces

Comment: Could you try this on Chrome JS console `"FROM {oj table1 left outer join table2 on table1.field1 = table2.field1}, table1, table3".match(/table1(?=,)/)`